# CMD command to recursively list all files in a folder with a sortorder without regard to location in a hierarchy?

Tags: sorting, recursion, cmd, directory, directory-listing

I've been trying to come up with a way to use DIR list all the files on a drive according to their date, but my issue is that the resulting list still goes folder to folder alphabetically, just as one would expect. Within the folders, the files are listed properly, that's not the problem. Cue possibly convoluted visuals.

This is the plain recursive directory listing (with a date column just because that happens to be what I want to sort against):

```
main                                     Date
 |                                       -----------------
 | -- file0_1.ext                        1/5/10 12:00:00AM
 | -- file0_2.ext                        1/1/10 12:00:00AM
 + -- sub1
 |     | -- file1_1.ext                  1/7/10 12:00:00AM
 |     | -- file1_2.ext                  1/4/10 12:00:00AM
 + -- sub2
 |     | -- file2_1.ext                  1/6/10 12:00:00AM
 + -- sub3
 |     | -- file3_1.ext                  1/2/10 12:00:00AM
 |     + -- sub3_1
 |     |     | -- file3_1_1.ext          1/3/10 12:00:00AM
```

When I run

```
dir *.* /s/od
```

to list all files recursively sorted by date, I get

```
main\file0_2.ext                         1/1/10 12:00:00AM
main\file0_1.ext                         1/5/10 12:00:00AM
main\sub1\file1_2.ext                    1/4/10 12:00:00AM
main\sub1\file1_1.ext                    1/7/10 12:00:00AM
main\sub2\file2_1.ext                    1/6/10 12:00:00AM
main\sub3\file3_1.ext                    1/2/10 12:00:00AM
main\sub3\sub3_1\file3_1_1.ext           1/3/10 12:00:00AM
```

where the folders are listed alphabetically, but the files are indeed correctly sorted by date within their folders. However, what I'm really shooting for is:

```
main\folder\file0_2.ext                  1/1/10 12:00:00AM
main\sub3\file3_1.ext                    1/2/10 12:00:00AM
main\sub3\sub3_1\file3_1_1.ext           1/3/10 12:00:00AM
main\sub1\file1_2.ext                    1/4/10 12:00:00AM
main\file0_1.ext                         1/5/10 12:00:00AM
main\sub2\file2_1.ext                    1/6/10 12:00:00AM
main\sub1\file1_1.ext                    1/7/10 12:00:00AM
```

where the files are listed regardless of their location in the hierarchy according to their date.

One workaround is to pipe all the output from a listing to a text file, parse it, sort it properly, and list it all again, but I'm really looking for a single command I can run within cmd.exe, so it can be easily implemented from memory on other Windows machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From memory

```
robocopy "c:\main" "c:\main" * /l /nocopy /is /s /njh /njs /nc /ns /ts | sort
```

That is, call `robocopy` checking files from the intended folder against the same folder, but only list files, do not copy anything, include same files, process subdirectories, without job header, without job summary, without class, without size, with time stamp, and pipes the output to `sort` to get the list.

If you only need the list of files

```
for /f "tokens=2,*" %a in ('robocopy "c:\main" "c:\main" * /l /nocopy /is /s /njh /njs /nc /ns /ts ^| sort') do @echo %b
```

Comment: Thanks! This did exactly what I wanted! I never would have expected the answer to lie within robocopy, but there it is. Now to see how I can play with this to do other neat things...

Comment: Can you verify it?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Except a typo error with a wrong quote symbol (a backtick instead of a single quote, now changed) in the `for` command, the rest of the answer works (tested on W10 64b) as long as you have `robocopy` in your system. What problem do you see?

Comment: Cool solution, but I need to do sorting by filename instead of timestamp, and preserve a column with subfolder (relative nested path inside "source"/"target"). It looks like robocopy can't do this.